# Adding Duplicate TreeNode Names to new branch where Nodes Contain Different Values

Tags: vb.net, list, visual-studio-2012, duplicates, treenode

I have already filtered out Tree-nodes into a list that contain the same Node Name with "IsDuplicateNodeName"[1].

I want to add the nodes from that lists into a child node with the same Children Name being expandable showing all the children with the same name with different internal Values, this is where I'm having trouble.[2]

I'm looking for something like this from the "nodeList" I already have.
NameDuplicate1
-NameDuplicate1
-NameDuplicate1
NameDuplicate2
-NameDuplicate2
-NameDuplicate2
-NameDuplicate2

[1]

```
Friend Sub HandleClassClicked(node As TreeNode)

        Dim classnode As TreeNode = node
        Dim [class] = DirectCast(node.Tag, System.Type)
        Dim nodeList As New List(Of TreeNode)

        'only returns public methods
        Dim publicmethods = From linqmethod In AssemblyHelper.GetMethods([class]) Where linqmethod.IsPublic

        If classnode.Nodes.Count = 0 Then
            For Each method In publicmethods
                If IsDuplicateNodeName(method.Name, method, node) Then 'Storing Duplicate Nodes
                    nodeList.Add(classnode)
                Else
                    classnode.Nodes.Add(BuildNode(method.Name, method)) 'If Unique adding to Tree
                End If
            Next
            AddDuplicateNodes(nodeList) 'This method handles the duplicate List of Nodes.
            classnode.Expand()
        End If
    End Sub
```

[2]

```
Friend Sub AddDuplicateNodes(nodeList As List(Of TreeNode))

        For Each node In nodeList 'Iterates through each node in list here
            'Need to add unique nodes (grouped together) as child nodes of original Tree.
        Next
    End Sub
```

Let me know if I need to clarify something, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution goes through each node and check if the current node in the 'for loop' has a matching name with the previous node just added to the tree.  This only works when you are sure the nodes will be sorted.  I'm using "Order By" to make sure of that.

```
 Friend Sub HandleClassClicked(node As TreeNode)

        Dim classnode As TreeNode = node
        Dim [class] = DirectCast(node.Tag, System.Type)
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Dim previousNode As TreeNode

        'only returns public methods that are always sorted
        Dim publicmethods = From linqmethod In AssemblyHelper.GetMethods([class]) Where linqmethod.IsPublic Order By linqmethod.Name

        If classnode.Nodes.Count = 0 Then
            For Each method In publicmethods
                If node.Nodes.Count > 1 AndAlso method.Name = node.Nodes.Item(count - 1).Name Then  
                'this line only check previous node after 1 has been added to the tree and only creates new children if the method.Name matches the previous node (node.Nodes.Item(count - 1).Name 

                    previousNode = node.Nodes.Item(count - 1) 'Selects previous node
                    previousNode.Nodes.Add(BuildNode(method.Name, method)) 'Adds duplicate to previous node.
                Else 'this will be a unique name case.
                    classnode.Nodes.Add(BuildNode(method.Name, method))
                    count += 1 'only increment count on unique cases or null reference will occur
                End If
            Next
            classnode.Expand() 'the tree will show expanded and sorted.
        End If
    End Sub
```

*Basic Node Builder

```
Private Function BuildNode(name As String, method As MethodInfo) As TreeNode

        Dim TreeNode As New TreeNode

        TreeNode.Name = name
        TreeNode.Text = name
        TreeNode.Tag = method
    Return TreeNode

End Function
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this answer is expected to solved the problem you are referring? How can be this helpful to anyone when most of the methods are not even shown? You have just adapted MY ALGORITHM to your needs?! When I (or any other person) writes an algorithm here expect you to adapt it to your exact situation to solve your exact problem but future readers do not care about this!? Impressive behaviour!! Taking my algorithm and writing your own answer with it! This is the last time I will help you (I rarely -1 and this is the only reason why you don't get 2 -1s really well deserved).

Comment: PS: you should refer the name of the person you stole the algorithm from.

Comment: Sorry, your answer did not solve my question, I re-wrote it and now it solves my specific question.  Why is that a problem?  If you would not have removed you answer, it would be obvious I am not using your algorithm, it is quite different.

Comment: You are using the same algorithm (= approach to the problem). You didn't know how to account for something (not too difficult, to be honest) and suddenly, magically you did?. Although your implementation might be different (not sure because relevant parts of your code are not present = that's why your answer does not have a real point here: you ask about a problem and you basically answer "I solved it", without showing most of the solution). My answer DID answer your problem (it was performing the actions you wanted independently upon the inputs; BTW I can undelete the answer if you wish).

Comment: ... feel free to prove me wrong: show me your inputs, let me undelete my answer and let's see if it delivers the solution or not.

Comment: You do not see what I have done. I am not calling any other subs to fix my problem, I am handling the problem in the for loop of HandleClassClicked. That's  it. Your implementation added one extra child node with all other duplicates, not what I needed. I found out having a List of Nodes as I had in my question (and as you answered) did not work, I am not using that list at all, I'm tackling the problem within this one sub. BuildNode is only adding values to the node, and was not a part my problem.  Why is it so hard to accept that I found an implementation that is different than what you did?

Comment: I told you what is hard to believe: that this is an actual answer, where most of what is required is missing; it is actually not even related to your original question. In your original question, you asked about the best way to deal with a list of nodes by performing the actions you wanted  (AddDuplicateNodes()); this was an acceptable question here (only partially focused on your problem and easily solvable/understandable outside your program). I did deliver an answer meeting your requirements EXACTLY (-> grouping all the repeated nodes, creating a new node and putting all them as children)

Comment: ... if your requirements weren't exactly like this, you might have explained me what you were exactly after (and, eventually, updated the question for future readers). But you just said that my answer wasn't delivering what you wanted (it was delivering perfectly what I understood that you want; perhaps you should have clarified something) and right away wrote your own one, suspiciously inspired in mine -> independently upon the result, a pretty censorable attitude IMHO. But if you consider that you didn't take anything (relevant) from my code and your problem is solved (not as you explained)

Comment: ... I apologise for the stealing part (but not for the other comments; I don't think that you should show this kind of behaviour with someone generously helping you). In any case, you should redo both your question and your answer to be truly relevant for SO; otherwise, this question/answer does not make any sense: nobody would be able to replicate (not even to understand it) your functionality just by looking at your code. You don't have upvoted answers and thus you are free to delete this question (-> although this is just my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for your help, hopefully this answer can help someone else in the future.

Comment: This was the whole point of my complain (well... and the "doing-it-by-your-own" + changing the rules on the go): adapt your question answer such that it can be helpful to others (this is what SO is about). As it is right now, it will certainly not be of any help. You should make an effort to show how you solved your problem exactly (using AddDuplicateNodes was an excellent way to accomplish that).

Comment: I updated my answer to better explain how my solution works, thanks for your input and help :)

Comment: OK. This is a bit better. I am 1+ing you (because of the making-it-clearer-to-others effort) but didn't like your behaviour anyway (from the point of view of the person helping you and from the one of future readers, by preferring your code rather than a general one).

Comment: PS: a while ago I +1ed you even without reading what you wrote (as said, just because of the helping-others attitude; I knew that your code was fine because mine was fine :)). But now I read it and is certainly funny: "I'm using "Order By" to make sure of that" (even though this code is NOT present in your answer) -> LOL, wasn't this the part you were complaining about in my answer? Ay!! I will never, ever understand people like you: what do you earn with this attitude? Not being helped ever again by a pretty helpful guy (myself)? And, eventually, being shown as a non-so-honest person?

Comment: (clarification: when I delete my answer because of the attitude of the asker, that means that I would not help this person again in a really, really long time... I might write some explanations like I did with you or don't say a word; but the result is always the same: if you are misusing SO or misappraising the help generously given to you, you are not the kind of person I want to help)... but even by ignoring the fact in brackets (what I would have applied anyway to you), this thing of the "Order By" have been really, really funny (thanks, I like smiling in the morning).

Comment: Glad I could make you smile :)

Comment: Glad that you are a so positive person ;)